# Mutual Information and Entropy calculation

Tags: probability, entropy, mutual-information

It is well known that Shannon's joint entropy ($H(X,Y)$) as well as mutual information ($I(X;Y)$) between two variables $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative based on Jensen's inequality. I read in a source that

$\begin{equation} 
I(X;Y)\div H(X,Y) \leq  1 
\end{equation}$

However I don't understand why and can find anywhere any proof of that. Can someone explain it to me or cite a source for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is by definition, as per the below:

[image]

`H(X,Y) := H(X|Y) + H(Y|X) + I(X;Y)`.

Please feel free to follow up if needing further assistance.

Comment: Already seen this equation but still can't figure it out perfectly, like all the summation is equal to 1 ? So, taking I(X,Y)\H(X,Y) is less or equal to 1 ?

Comment: Are you saying you don't understand why the inequality follows from the equation? Each of the three terms are greater than or equal to zero--entropy is not negative. So the sum of the terms must be equal to or greater than any of the individual terms. That's just arithmetic.